# VBA count color code not working properly with some blank cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following count color code, which is working fine until the range contains blank cells, for which you have to go in the function line and press enter, then the change into different kind of blank cells it seems, as i spotted the errors and everytime i do the step, the vba code is working again. How can I either correct the vba code so I can step this manual enter process for some blank cells, or is there an code that does the manual process for a certain range automatically?

```
Public Function SumByColor(pRange1 As Range, pRange2 As Range) As Double 
    'Update 20140210 
     Application.Volatile 
     Dim rng As Range 
     Dim xTotal As Double 
     xTotal = 0 
     For Each rng In pRange1 
         If rng.Font.Color = pRange2.Font.Color Then 
              xTotal = xTotal + rng.Value 
         End If 
     Next 
     SumByColor = xTotal 
End Function
```

Comment: The code should be working with blank cells automatically (at least on my end). Are you sure you are not on Manual Calcualtion in Excel?

Comment: `If Isnumeric(rng.Value) then xTotal = xTotal + rng.Value` should handle that

Comment: Hi Vityata, the calculation is on automatic. As said, its just for SOME blank cells where it causes an #value error.

Comment: Hi Rory, which part has to be replaced by your code suggestion?

Comment: @Robert replace the line `xTotal = xTotal + rng.Value` with the line that Rory suggested, and it should work... As if the cell doesn't contain a numeric value, it will skip the calculation...

Comment: Thanks Xabier and Rory, it works now!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your function work for me. I don't know what settings do you have, but try mine modification:

```
Public Function SumByColor(pRange1 As Range, pRange2 As Range) As Double
    'Update 20140210
     Application.Volatile
     Dim rng As Range
     Dim rngSum As Range

     For Each rng In pRange1
         If rng.Font.Color = pRange2.Font.Color And IsNumeric(rng.Value) Then
            If rngSum Is Nothing Then
                Set rngSum = rng
            Else
                Set rngSum = Union(rngSum, rng)
            End If
         End If
     Next
     SumByColor = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rngSum)
End Function
```

There is issue however for both mine and your version. It won't recalculate if you change font color for any cell. You must click Calculate Now in Formulas menu.